# How to get headers of an URL using PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm having troubles getting the proper headers from an url...

Let's say I have this URL: http://filetest.php?number=10&test=yes&year=2014

I want to get every headers values and print them in a HTML table that way:

```
| number |   |   | 1 | 0 |
| test   |   | y | e | s |
| year   | 2 | 0 | 1 | 4 |
```

I know $_GET['number'] will return '10', but how do I get the header name 'number'?

Now, what if I don't know the header is called 'number'? Can I store all the headers in an array? How?

And how can I output the results in the HTML array?

Thank you for your help, I really need it!

Comment: it's called query string. Try `echo '<pre>'.print_r( $_GET, true ).'</pre>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the query string. And then use `parse_str()`:

```
$qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($qs, $params);
var_dump($params);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["number"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["test"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
  ["year"]=>
  string(4) "2014"
}
```

Now you can loop through the array using a `foreach`, like so:

```
foreach ($params as $param => $val) {
    // Display the HTML table
    // Use str_split($val) to split the value into characters
}
```